# Swift 3. Cast Any to class which conforms specific protocol

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I have a random protocol as example

```
protocol testP {
    init(param1: String)
}
```

And I have a class, which take `Any` as parameter as example:

```
class testC {
    var aClass: Any
}
```

How can I check if `aClass` conforms to protocol `testP` and if it does, create a new object using protocol initializer, as example:

```
let newObject = aClass(param1: "Hello World!")
```

Please, help

Comment: Are you assigning an instance of a type that conforms to `testP` to `aClass`, or are you assigning the metatype of a type that conforms to `testP`?

Comment: Isn't the purpose of this kind of protocol to write `var aClass: testP` to do all these checks at compile time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test it as other type checking with `if-let`:

```
protocol TestP {
    init(param1: String)
}

class TestC {
    var aClass: Any

    init(_ aClass: Any) {
        self.aClass = aClass
    }
}

class MyClassA: TestP {
    required init(param1: String) {
        //
    }
}

class MyClassB {

}

let containerA = TestC(MyClassA.self)

let containerB = TestC(MyClassB.self)

if let testPType = containerA.aClass as? TestP.Type {
    var a = testPType.init(param1: "abc")
    print(a) //->MyClassA
}

if let testPType = containerB.aClass as? TestP.Type {
    print("This print statement is not executed")
}
```

---

By the way, if you assign only class types to  `aClass`, consider using `AnyClass` or `Any.Type`.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly